# How do i restore a solution file from folder view or sync them

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2022, solution

How do I resolve a discrepancy between the files shown in my .NET Winforms Project's .sln file and the files in the folder view, where the folder view includes commits that are not reflected in the .sln file, and attempting to create a new .sln file from the folder view results in the old, incomplete .sln file being used instead?

At this point the .sln is literally empty and the folder view holds the recent commit. Trying to add a existing Project from the .csproj, will give me a obsolete state of data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the Issue with **Menu** -> **File** -> **New** -> **Project from existing code** and then replaced the obsolete project-file with the folder view